# Cycle through classes on Jquery to animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIHZR.png)

I'm trying to create an animation where if you click the button the circles animate around the path and changes size. I'm not sure how i would cycle the classes on the next click ?

http://bluemoontesting.co.uk/bluemoon2016/people.html

I'm using an svg and have targeted the elements with this so far:

```
<script>
$(".animate-slider").click(function() { 
$('.st7').toggleClass("top-left");
$('#XMLID_292_').toggleClass("left");
$('#XMLID_293_').toggleClass("center-right");
$('#XMLID_297_').toggleClass("top-right");
$('#XMLID_301_').toggleClass("top");
$('#XMLID_283_').toggleClass("top-center");
 });
</script>
```

If anyone could help me i'd be very grateful :)

Thanks

Comment: When you say "on the next click", do you mean you want to do one transition on every click or the whole sequence on the first click and then maybe reset it?

Comment: Hi, my objective is that on each click the circles will swap classes. If you go to the link i supplied http://bluemoontesting.co.uk/bluemoon2016/people.html and click 'animate' you'll see them animate is size and position. I want this to basically keep looping so the circle with the text will travel around. Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Keep looping without the button click, you mean?

Comment: No, the button needs to be clicked but each time you click it the circles will change position and size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a little different approach. Instead of toggling classes, to get it to move to more than two positions, you will need to cycle the classes assigned to each element instead. Storing the class names in an array would allow you to move them in the array to cycle the position that each element moves to next. I created a [simplified example](https://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/d8k62wwr/).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var steps = ['right', 'bottom-right', 'bottom-left', 'left', 'top'],
    allClasses = steps.join(' ');
  $('#go').click(function() {
    $('#a').removeClass(allClasses).addClass(steps[0]);
    $('#b').removeClass(allClasses).addClass(steps[1]);
    $('#c').removeClass(allClasses).addClass(steps[2]);
    $('#d').removeClass(allClasses).addClass(steps[3]);
    $('#e').removeClass(allClasses).addClass(steps[4]);
    steps.push(steps.shift()); // move first element to the end

    // to cycle in the other direction you would pop and unshift instead
    // steps.unshift(steps.pop()); // move last element to the beginning
  });

});
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you for helping me :)

Comment: Hi, thanks again for helping me with this one. Really appreciate it. I'm wondering if you can give me an insight on how to develop it further. What i would really like to do is when the user clicks on the circle it goes to the class '#c' and the other circles rotate with it. Is there an obvious way to do this? Or is it really hard?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use setInterval like so:

```
var $st7 = $('.st7'); //class selectors can be expensive, so cache them
function rotate() { 
   $st7.toggleClass("top-left");
   $('#XMLID_292_').toggleClass("left");
   $('#XMLID_293_').toggleClass("center-right");
   $('#XMLID_297_').toggleClass("top-right");
   $('#XMLID_301_').toggleClass("top");
   $('#XMLID_283_').toggleClass("top-center");
}

//2000 is milliseconds, so that's two seconds
var rotateIntervalId = setInterval(rotate, 2000);

//optionally consider stopping/starting the effect on mouse hover/exit
$('#Layer_1').on('hover', function() {
   clearInterval(rotateIntervalId);
}).on('blur', function() {
   rotateIntervalId = setInterval(rotate, 2000);
});
```